# Can the stdout (1) file descriptor be re-used after closing?

Tags: file-descriptors, system-calls

I first call close(1) and then later open a file using open() syscall.

Is it possible that open() returns 1 because it will use the lowest free file descriptor?

I have read that open() uses the lowest free file descriptor [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, fd 1 will be re-used. Try this:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    close(1);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY));
}
```